# Getting "500 Unknown command" when uploading a file to FTP in Python with FTP.storbinary

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to upload a file to FTP.   I am trying to upload a file to `/public_html` on `files.000webhost.com` but I keep getting   `ftplib.error_perm: 500 Unknown command`

My code is below:

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('files.000webhost.com','hazaaay','dwadawdadw')
file = r'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\A csv\\a csv1.csv','b'                  # file to send
session.storbinary('a csv1.csv', file)     # send the file
file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```

Despite giving unresolved reference, it says in console that process finished with exit code 0 though it is not showing up in FileZilla.  Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the command in the [`FTP.storbinary` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary).

> Store a file in binary transfer mode. ***command* should be an appropriate `STOR` command: `"STOR filename"`.**

```
session.storbinary('STOR a csv1.csv', file)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)